# Delete lines which contains numbers in python

Tags: python, regex, file

I have to copy a file but before that I need to remove the lines with numbers.

this is my file:

```
0:00:00.000,0:00:06.410
let's start with

0:00:04.470,0:00:10.769
something

0:00:06.410,0:00:12.360
easy
```

and I want to have something like this:

```
let's start with something easy
```

and this is my code :

```
readFile = open("file.sbv")
writeFile = open("newwordlist.sbv","w")

for line in readFile: 
    newline = line.rstrip('\r\n')
    writeFile.write(newline)
readFile.close()
writeFile.close()
```

Comment: try using `readFile.readlines()` -- this will return a list of lines.  Then you can filter on the ones containing numbers.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 depends on if the file is large or not, you may not want the entire file in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need regex for this, you can simply use `any(i.isdigit() for i in line)`:

```
with open('in.txt') as infile, open('out.txt', 'w') as outfile:
  for line in infile:
    if not any(i.isdigit() for i in line):
      outfile.write(line)
```

> in.txt

```
0:00:00.000,0:00:06.410
let's start with
0:00:04.470,0:00:10.769
something
0:00:06.410,0:00:12.360
easy
```

> out.txt

```
let's start with
something
easy
```

If you want the results on one line, you can write `line.rstrip('\r\n')` instead of `line`, however this is dependent on which line-endings your file is using, it may be just `\n`.

Comment: this is good, but I think OP wanted to get rid of the line breaks

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `re.search` to identify the number lines.  Assuming the line does *not* match this pattern, then you would write it out:

```
readFile = open("file.sbv")
writeFile = open("newwordlist.sbv","w")

for line in readFile: 
    newline = line.rstrip('\r\n')
    if not re.search(r'^\d:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3},\d:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}$', newline, re.M|re.I)
        writeFile.write(newline)
readFile.close()
writeFile.close()
```

This answer assumes that maybe you do have lines which contain numbers, but you don't want to remove those.  The pattern I used targets the timestamp lines in your sample data.